# how does clojure add line numbers in the meta of an evaluated defn?

Tags: clojure

I've been playing around with the `meta` function and just for fun, I placed a meta around a function definition and evaluated it in emacs... I got this output:

```
(meta  (defn has-signal [sigtype]
         (fn [ex]
           (-> ex ex-data :ribol.core/signal (= sigtype)))))

=> {:ns #<Namespace ribol.test-ribol>, :name has-signal, 
    :arglists ([sigtype]), :column 8, :line 1, :file "NO_SOURCE_PATH"}
```

How is this happening? how does clojure know what line number and what namespace the function is at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler knows this at the point that the code is evaled. It's the same process by which stack traces work.

If you eval in the repl, then this information is missing (NO_SOURCE_PATH) which is a pain.